# How to insert a symbol at previous index for CorePlot real-time plotting?

Tags: swift, plot, real-time, core-plot, symbols

As title, I want to insert a symbol at previous index for real-time plotting like the image below.

I have to do some computation in order to get the location of peak value so that the symbol index(e.g. index = 1) and the real-time scatter index (e.g. idx = 5) would not the same.

How to add a symbol in previous index?

Please help me, thanks!!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the plot's `-insertDataAtIndex:numberOfRecords:` method to add data. The starting index can be anything between zero (to add data before all of the existing data) and the number of existing data points (to add data at the end). If you add new points before existing ones, the existing ones are shifted over to make room. Keep that in mind if you reload the plot data after inserting new points—the indices of the old points will change.